# Is $3^{2015}-2^{2015}$ a prime?

Tags: number-theory

I encountered this question when I took the Mathematics Aptitude Test yesterday and I had no clue how to approach it.

The question goes quite simply, "Is $3^{2015}-2^{2015}$ a prime? Show it very carefully."

I had knowledge about the fact that $x^n-y^n=(x-y)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}y+\cdots+xy^{n-2}+y^{n-1})$. It gives

$3^{2015}-2^{2015}=(3-2)(3^{2014}+3^{2013}\times 2+\cdots+3\times 2^{2013}+2^{2014})=3^{2014}+3^{2013}\times 2+\cdots+3\times 2^{2013}+2^{2014}$.

I hope some kind souls can give me some thoughts how to proceed on. Thank you!

Comment: $a-b$ divides $a^n-b^n$, that's all you need to know.

Comment: Do you know how the polynomial $x^3 - y^3$ factors? More generally, polynomials of the form $x^n - y^n$ factor nicely into pieces across odd factors of $n$. Here, since $2015$ has many odd prime factors, it factors nicely. I would add that @IvanNeretin is slightly mistaken, as in this case $3 - 2 = 1$. But the idea of there being guaranteed factors is a correct one.

Comment: Are you kidding??? You've published this question yesterday and somebody gave you a perfect (and short) answer!

Comment: @IvanNeretin: That wouldn't help for primality test, as $a-b=1$ in this case.

Comment: No, $a-b=211$ (and many other things too) in this case. Who said $(a,b)=(3,2)$? That's only one of the options, and (as you pointed out) not a very useful one. What if we consider $(a,b)=(3^5,2^5)$?

Comment: @barakmanos is that so? I cannot find the previous question.

Comment: @mixedmath: Was probably deleted.

Comment: So you've just edited the question and added the notion that $3^{2015}-2^{2015}=(3-2)(3^{2014}+3^{2013}\times 2+\cdots+3\times 2^{2013}+2^{2014})$. Now, assuming this is correct, it very explicitly answers your own question, don't you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** $$3^5 \equiv 2^5 \mod 211.$$

Comment: But $211$ is prime, so how does that help?

Comment: Well, $3^{2015} - 2^{2015}$ is clearly larger than $211$ and the above can be used to show that $211$ divides it.

Comment: Do you mean $3^{2015}\equiv(3^5)^{403}\equiv32^{403}$ and $2^{2015}\equiv(2^5)^{403}\equiv32^{403}$?

Comment: $3^{5} \equiv 2^{5} \mod 211$ implies $3^{2015} = (3^5)^{403} \equiv (2^5)^{403} = 2^{2015} \mod 211$, so $211 \mid 3^{2015} - 2^{2015}$.